# If frame = X go back to frame 1

Tags: flash, actionscript

Hi I have an animation I'm working on and when it reaches a certain frame it goes back to 0.

so basically

```
stop();

button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Animation);
function Animation(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
    if(currentFrame==150){
     gotoAndStop(1)
}

}

stop();
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Graph);
function Graph(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(300);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(currentFrame==5){
     gotoAndPlay(1)
}
```

Even if your work isn't directly involved in action script coding, it can be greatly beneficial to have minimal knowledge of as3. I would highly recommend a beginner to read *Learning ActionScipt 3.0* by Rich Shupe.

Also be sure next time to clarify what you're trying to ask.

**Update:**

put this code on frame1:

```
stop();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playAnimation);
function playAnimation(e:MouseEvent){
    play();
}
```

code for final frame of animation:

```
gotoAndPlay(1);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response,  I'm having a little trouble I want it to play my animation on click but stop and return to frame 1 when it reaches frame 150.  My code has been added to the question when hitting frame 150 the animation carries on running.

Comment: no problem @rory, I've added the code to my answer above